# I need a help to set up Digital Ocean nameservers

Tags: dns, hosting, digital-ocean, nameservers

I have a VPS server on Digital Ocean and I need to set up this server to host multiple domains with cPanel. I've been trying for 2 days and I can not understand the logic.

My domain is **sbcw.com.br**

I would like that at the end of this process my domain have function as the nameservers shown in the example below:

```
DOMAIN      : mycustomer.com
NAMESERVERS : ns1.sbcw.com.br
              ns2.sbcw.com.br
```

I need help to successfully configure the records to use my domain as a nameserver for other domains and I have little experience in this segment.

> The attachment corresponds to some attempts to find the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the IPs and configure the name servers in WHM as

ns1.sbcw.com.br
ns2.sbcw.com.br

Make sure you have A records added for the name servers on the server with their IPs.

Contact your domain registrar where the domain sbcw.com.br is hosted and register those name servers in order to make them active. Those name servers should ping.

Make sure you have DNS zone created in WHM for the domain sbcw.com.br with the name servers assigned.